# How to format this String "2015-06-22T09:40:30+01:00" in dd/MM/yyyy at hh:mm format?

Tags: java, date, time, format

How to format the String `"2015-06-22T09:40:30+01:00"` in `dd/MM/yyyy at hh:mm`  format?

Comment: Please search before asking. Even though Meno Hochschild is quite fast (this time), you can get your answer still faster by searching.

Answer (score 3):

The input format follows ISO-8601, hence you can do this (using Java-8-class `OffsetDateTime`):

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("2015-06-22T09:40:30+01:00");
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy 'at' HH:mm");
System.out.println(dtf.format(odt)); // 22/06/2015 at 09:40
```

By the way, I have changed your pattern from "...hh:mm" to "...HH:mm" because I assume that you want the hour of day, not of half-day which would not make sense without specifying am/pm.

Comment: Thank you very much for quick answer.